# Why UDP receive buffer size(rx_queue) is not increasing?

Tags: java, linux, networking, udp, buffer

In my java server Application, 1000 UDP packets are coming per second. But my application can process only 100 packets/sec. So there are like 900 UDP packets/sec that my server can not process.

The server application is doing something like this.

```
    while(true)
    {
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        process(receivePacket); // takes around 50ms to complete
        serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }
```

From my understanding, those unprocessed packets are getting stored in OS's UDP receive buffer. when this buffer will become full OS will drop those packets.

But the problem is when I run the command to see my UDP buffer size.

```
cat /proc/net/udp
```

It shows that there is nothing stored on my UDP socket buffer

```
 cat /proc/net/udp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops             
   4: FCA9C11F:C36F 8C719AC6:0035 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 2983494501 2 ffff880169aff4c0 0     
   5: FCA9C11F:D3F0 8C719AC6:0035 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 2983494485 2 ffff8801b9bbedc0 0     
  16: 7A52BB59:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    38        0 2438608536 2 ffff8807656764c0 0     
  16: A2EE0D55:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    38        0 2438608045 2 ffff88077ccdd7c0 0     
  16: A58F466D:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    38        0 2438607809 2 ffff8801129f6240 0
```

It shows there is no packet drop and tx_queue and rx_queue are 0 in size. So there are no packets stored in UDP receive buffer?

But if I take a tcpdump, then I can see that lots of packets a coming to the server and server can process only 10% all those packets. so the other 90% should be stored in the UDP receive buffer.

What am i missing or not understanding?

Comment: It would be best if you share some part of your code. Are you using any event-driven code to get the packets? Maybe it's not about your recv buffer.

Comment: added server-side sudo code. Its simple java code. java socket recieves packet, process it and sends response.

Comment: You should defer your process method onto some other thread as well as integrate event-driven technique. I'm not much familiar with java event driven techniques, but there should be some way to do it.

Comment: actually, my question was why UDP receive buffer size is not increasing. right now the processing takes 10ms due to a faulty code but it will actually take less than 1ms.

Comment: What have you done to increase the UDP buffer ? Have you done any tuning?